# Java get all Links from Youtube Playlist

Tags: java, powershell, networking, jsoup

With following Powershell script I can extract all links of a playlist from Youtube:

```
$Playlist = ((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.youtube.com/watch? 
v=dyJdLalc7TA&list=PLNmsVeXQZj7q0ao69AIogD94oBgp3E9Zs").Links | Where {$_.class -match "playlist-video"}).href

ForEach ($Video in $Playlist) {
 $s ="https://www.youtube.com" + $Video
 $s =$s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf('&'))
  Write-Output ($s)
 }
```

I need this for a java Youtubeplayer so i tried it with jsoup:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/watch? 
v=dyJdLalc7TA&list=PLNmsVeXQZj7q0ao69AIogD94oBgp3E9Zs").get();

        //Get links from document object. 
        Elements links = document.select("a[href]");


        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println("Link: " + link.attr("href"));               
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

But I can't extract the right links with it. Does anybody have a idea how to do it with java and without using youtube api ? 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar projects in the past.

Each link in a youtube playlist is in an element called `ytd-playlist-video-renderer`.
I suggest you look for this element, then for an `<a>` element and then for the href tag using `substring("").`

```
String source = getSource();
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();

while(source.contains("ytd-playlist-video-renderer")){

    source = source.substring(source.indexOf("ytd-playlist-video-renderer"));
    source = source.substring(source.indexOf("<a"));
    source = source.substring(source.indexOf("href="));
    links.add(1, source.indexOf);

}
```

This calls a function `getSource()` to get the html-source code and then extracts the links from it. (Didn't test this so, I'll just pray it works)

Here are some related GitHub Projects I've done. Feel free to check out the actually tested code: [KarmaGrapher](https://github.com/DapfiDuck/KarmaGrapher/blob/master/KarmaGrapher/src/capture/StatReader.java) that extracts the Karma of a reddit Post and puts it in a  csv-file, and this very old project of mine: [TagHack](https://github.com/DapfiDuck/TagHack/blob/master/Tag_Hack1.0.zip) which ectracts the youtube tags from the source code. (The Code is in a Zip file. I am gringing so hard)

Comment: ok thank you. But when i wite for example this:   for(int i=0; i<source.length() -15; i++) {
       
       if(source.substring(i,i+14).equals("playlist-video")) {
        System.out.println(i);
       }
       
      } i got only 1-2 hits and in the playlist are over 60 videos

Comment: with the powershell code I got all links in the html source, but when i try it to get the source with java don't.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution not good, but it works now. I call the powershell script with a processbuilder and return the links to the java program.

Comment: if you are not familiar with https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/ it might be of some interest to you. players like https://mpv.io/ can hook into it